# Reading JSON from file using JSON.NET - Cannot implicitly convert type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken' to 'string'

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm trying to read the following JSON from a file using JSON.NET.

```
{
    "SendTelemetry": true
}
```

However, I'm having some issues with parsing the data. Here's what I have so far.

```
public class SettingsStore
{
    [JsonProperty]
    public bool SendTelemetry { get; set; }

    public dynamic ReadJsonFile(string filePath)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(filePath)) { throw new ArgumentNullException("filePath"); }

        if (!File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            throw new FileNotFoundException(string.Format(@"JSON settings file not found at [{0}]", filePath));
        }

        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(File.ReadAllText(filePath));
    }

    public void WriteJsonFile(string fileDirectory, string filePath, string json)
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(fileDirectory))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(fileDirectory);
        }

        File.WriteAllText(filePath, json);
    }
}

var rootDir = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(@"%localappdata%\LigerShark\SideWaffle\");
var filePath = Path.Combine(rootDir, "SideWaffle-Settings.json");
settings = new SettingsStore();
string json = settings.ReadJsonFile(filePath);
bool telemetry = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SettingsStore>(json.ToString()).SendTelemetry;
```

When it gets to the point of deserializing the json I get the error `Cannot implicitly convert type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken' to 'string'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)` I've been going through the JSON.NET documentation but I know I'm missing something. Can someone please help point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are having an issue is with you de serialization returning a `JToken` as you have not casted your result.

I would suggest changing your methods slightly to have the `ReadJsonFile` return an instance of `SettingsStore` and this method being `static` (as no need for an instance if you are creating a new object).

Something like this looks like it should do the trick.

```
public class SettingsStore
{
    [JsonProperty]
    public bool SendTelemetry { get; set; }

    public static SettingsStore ReadJsonFile(string filePath)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(filePath)) { throw new ArgumentNullException("filePath"); }

        if (!File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            throw new FileNotFoundException(string.Format(@"JSON settings file not found at [{0}]", filePath));
        }

        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SettingsStore>(File.ReadAllText(filePath));
    }

    public void WriteJsonFile(string fileDirectory, string filePath, string json)
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(fileDirectory))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(fileDirectory);
        }

        File.WriteAllText(filePath, json);
    }
}
```

This is easily called in one line using.

```
var settings = SettingsStore.ReadJsonFile("....");
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're calling `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject()` twice - once in `ReadJsonFile()` and once in the code at the bottom.  You should only need to call it once, so I'd get rid of the call to `settings.ReadJsonFile()` and instead do:

```
bool telemetry = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SettingsStore>(File.ReadAllText(filePath)).SendTelemetry;
```

(of course, you can move that into a method if you'd prefer so you can add back the checks on `filePath`)

Answer (score 1):

`ReadJsonFile` is returning a `JToken`, as you're already deserializing the object.

Change your code to this:

```
public class SettingsStore
{
    [JsonProperty]
    public bool SendTelemetry { get; set; }

    public static SettingsStore ReadJsonFile(string filePath)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(filePath)) { throw new ArgumentNullException("filePath"); }

        if (!File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            throw new FileNotFoundException(string.Format(@"JSON settings file not found at [{0}]", filePath));
        }

        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SettingsStore>(File.ReadAllText(filePath));
    }

    public void WriteJsonFile(string fileDirectory, string filePath, string json)
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(fileDirectory))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(fileDirectory);
        }

        File.WriteAllText(filePath, json);
    }
}
```

And then:

```
var rootDir = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(@"%localappdata%\LigerShark\SideWaffle\");
var filePath = Path.Combine(rootDir, "SideWaffle-Settings.json");
var settingsStore = SettingsStore.ReadJsonFile(filePath);
bool telemetry = settingsStore.SendTelemetry;
```